# flutter: ITMS-90683: Missing Purpose String in Info.plist

Tags: flutter, app-store, app-store-connect

after successfully uploading my app to appstore connect, i get this email from apple:

> Dear Developer,
>
> We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app,
> "Tamata" 2.0.0 (8). Please correct the following issues, then upload
> again.
>
> ITMS-90683: Missing Purpose String in Info.plist - Your app's code
> references one or more APIs that access sensitive user data. The app's
> Info.plist file should contain a NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key
> with a user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and completely
> why your app needs the data. Starting Spring 2019, all apps submitted
> to the App Store that access user data are required to include a
> purpose string. If you're using external libraries or SDKs, they may
> reference APIs that require a purpose string. While your app might not
> use these APIs, a purpose string is still required. You can contact
> the developer of the library or SDK and request they release a version
> of their code that doesn't contain the APIs. Learn more
> (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/protecting_the_user_s_privacy).
>
> Best regards,
>
> The App Store Team

i am not collecting any user data related to pictures/images, heres my info.plist:
[image]

whats the problem?

Comment: Goodday... just to clarify does your app have any functionality that accesses the device... ex: downloading image/file or opening images from the photo library?

Answer (score 2):

Probably one of the third-party library, that you have in you dependencies, has code that can fire request for photos. There are two ways to handle that:

- Put `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` to your info.plist, and have hope that some library not fire request for gallery. User won't see permission dialog, until request for photos wouldn't fire.
- Find this library and change it for another lib, that doesn't have request for photos. To find out what lib can fire request, search phrase `Gallery` or `Photo` on every lib in `.pub-cache` directory and try to localize request for that permission. In AndroidStudio, on the `Project` view, you can navigate all libs in `External Libraries` tabs and perform search by `ctrl+shift+F`.